# run command within Vim (but from a different directory)

Tags: vim

I would like to run **pdflatex** from within vim to update the pdf file I'm currently working editing, which is a chapter-xx.tex file.  My main problem is that my chapter-xx.tex file is just an input file within my MASTER.tex file, which is in another directory.

I can try this:

```
:!pdflatex template/MASTER.tex
```

That does run **pdflatex** on my MASTER.tex file, which has my chapter-xx.tex file as an input file.  However, **pdflatex** can't find my input files.  I believe this is because my current working directory is that of the chapter-xx.tex file that I'm currently working on.  The input file paths inside MASTER.tex file are all relative to it's own directory structure.  From bash, where template/MASTER.tex resides, it has zero problems.  But inside my chapter-xx.tex file, which is one directory down. ( ../) from MASTER.tex, it can't find the input other .tex files, which are input files within MASTER.tex

I believe the question I need to ask is how to change the current working directory then run the **pdflatex** command, while still working in my chapter-xx.tex file.

by the way, each chapter has actual numbers rather than "xx" by the way.
Also, **pdflatex** takes a text file (.tex) and converts it into a pdf file.  A .tex file can also import other .tex files, which is my case.  I have one MASTER.tex file, with numerous imports of other tex files, such as Chapters.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13612/executing-a-shell-command-in-the-parent-directory

Comment: PERFECT works great!

Comment: Why don't you simply start Vim from `MASTER.tex`'s directory?

Comment: In the future I plan to move all the files into one folder.  Also, starting in the MASTER.tex directory works too.. (I'm don't know why, but I hadn't thought of that!!)